# Convert cUrl to rest in Apex?

Tags: apex, apexrest, curl

I have a curl request which I have to convert to a rest request in Apex. This is the request:

```
   curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions \
  -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc: \
  -d customer=customer_id\
  -G
```

And this is the code I used:

```
HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
req1.setMethod('GET');
req1.setEndpoint('https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions');

String urlBody = 'customer='+ customerId;
String username = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc';
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username);
String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + username;
req1.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

req1.setBody(urlBody);
Http binding1 = new Http();
HttpResponse response1 = binding1.send(req1);
```

I have converted many curl to rest in the same way. But, this is the only cURL thats not working. This is the response I am getting:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
    "message": "Missing required param: items.",
    "param": "items",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

I think the only difference that this cURL has is there is an extra `-G` at the end of the cURL. I think thats creating the problem. Also, I have run the cURL on the Postman and its returning data fine. So, whats wrong with my converting?

Comment: are you trying to retrieve the subscription?

Comment: @User6670 yes. i am.

Comment: in the documentation of stripe i see the following curl to retrieve the subscription curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_HJ3fAVru2hvtxY \
  -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc:

Comment: they dont mention customerid in there just the subscriptionid

Comment: yeah.. but i dont know the subscription id. i only know customer id. thats why i am using the above request.

Comment: i did see this  api which can get you customer subscription ->https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_HJ3f4cSLOxY9a6/subscriptions

Comment: could u give me the link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following api can get you customer subscription

```
HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
req1.setMethod('GET');
String customerId='cus_HJ3f4cSLOxY9a6';
string endpoint='https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/'+customerId+'/subscriptions';
req1.setEndpoint(endpoint);

String username = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc';
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username);
String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + username;
req1.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

Http binding1 = new Http();
HttpResponse response1 = binding1.send(req1);
system.debug(response1);
system.debug(response1.getBody());
```

Comment: thanks very much